# NixOS installation on multi-boot system with GRUB (from Arch installation)

Tags: arch-linux, grub2, lvm, luks, nixos

I have one physical disk (`/dev/sda`) which is divided in `/dev/sda1` (which is `/boot` bootable GRUB2 partition used and setup with Arch) and `/dev/sda2` which is my `cryptroot` that, when unlocked, is a single large `lvmpool` with the full size of the partition `/dev/sda2`. I have installed Arch on 3 `lvs`, as seen in the image below.
This setup is basically LVM on LUKS as described on the Arch Wiki on Dm-crypt.

[image: partition layout and lvs]

Since I read lots of great things about NixOS, I am trying to install NixOS next to my current Arch install, so I created 3 more `lvs` similar to the `arch-` `lvs` above, and I followed the NixOS installation guide. I have specified `boot.loader.grub.device = "nodev"` so that NixOS will not install GRUB anywhere else, because I want to re-use my existing GRUB2 from Arch which resides on `/dev/sda1`. It will however write a `grub.cfg` file for NixOS to `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` that, in this case, is on the NixOS `nix-root` `lv` (`/`, the filesystem root in NixOS) and thus not on the actual (bootable) GRUB2 partition `/dev/sda1`.

However, to achieve that, I want to add an extra menu-entry to my `grub.cfg` and point to the `configfile` that the NixOS-installer has created on my `nix-root` `lv` (`/`, the filesystem root in NixOS), pretty much what is described [here](http://lists.science.uu.nl/pipermail/nix-dev/2015-August/017955.html). However, I am unsure how to create an entry that will point to the `nix-root` `lv`, since it seems that GRUB wants some syntax like `set root='(hd0,X)'`, but how can I make something like this `set root` aware of my `lv` to point to instead of to a physical disk and partition number? Both the options `configfile` and `chainloader` are not very well-described in GRUB, and neither is the `set root` as far as I could find.

I hope that somebody could point me in the right direction, tell me what I am doing wrong or why/how I am making this too hard on myself, to just use one bootable GRUB2 partition for multiple Linux distributions that reside on different LVM `lvs` on LUKS.

**EDIT:**
I tried various options for `set root=` such as `(lv/nix-root)`, `(lvmpool/nix-root)` and `(/dev/mapper/lvmpool-nix--root)`, however the problem is that the LVM `lvs` seem not visible to GRUB yet, since at the point that GRUB loads, `/dev/sda2/` is still an encrypted LUKS `cryptroot`.

Comment: Grub2 [does support](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub.html#Device-syntax) syntaxes other than `(hd0,X)`.

Comment: @AlexanderBatischev thank you for your reply, I just stumbled upon the same documentation piece, and tried various options for `set root=` such as `(lv/nix-root)`, `(lvmpool/nix-root)` and `(/dev/mapper/lvmpool-nix--root)`, however the problem is that the LVM `lvs` seem not visible to GRUB yet, since at the point that GRUB loads, `/dev/sda2/` is still an encrypted LUKS `cryptroot`.

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Can you update the post? I glanced at my own `grub.cfg` (I too have LVM on LUKS, but my `/boot` is on that same encrypted partition, so it's a bit different from yours), and it uses `set root=(lvmid/A/B)`, where `A` is "VG UUID" and `B` is "LV UUID" (can be obtained with `vgdisplay` and `lvdisplay`).

Comment: @AlexanderBatischev I found out, thanks to your information together with this (super useful) post with information: [Help manually booting from GRUB console into crypt -> LVM -> root)](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/2wm7oq/help_manually_booting_from_grub_console_into/). I am going to update my original question and write out the answer as soon as I can! Thanks again!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the help above from Alexander Batischev, and some [very useful information](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/2wm7oq/help_manually_booting_from_grub_console_into/cp0mqlc) from Reddit user `cookie_enthusiast` on the [`/r/linuxquestions`](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions) page on Reddit, I managed to get this working.

It turns out that GRUB2 works well with UUIDs, and not so well with device names. With this knowledge in mind, we need the following 4 UUIDs at hand, before we can (manually) create an extra GRUB menuentry to our NixOS `grub.cfg` `configfile`:

1. The UUID of the LUKS device.
2. The UUID of the LVM Volume Group.
3. The UUID of the LVM Logical Volume.
4. The UUID of the filesystem containing the `grub.cfg` file we want to load via the `configfile` directive in GRUB2.

I will list here how to obtain these four UUIDs:

1. Execute `cryptsetup luksUUID /dev/sda2` and **remove all the dashes (`-`) from the UUID**, `a0cb535a-8468-485f-a220-a5f49e85c9f4` would become `a0cb535a8468485fa220a5f49e85c9f4` in my case.
2. Execute `vgdisplay` and look for the `VG UUID`, `lvmpool` with UUID `5atKN9-PQBi-T9wb-Iyz8-qP4y-HN2E-c5uLOT` in my case.
3. Execute `lvdisplay` and look for the `LV UUID` of the LV Name or LV Path that contains your `grub.cfg` file, `nix-root` or `/dev/lvmpool/nix-root` with UUID `C9zkjF-IHu0-qQkP-KgLf-8rAy-TVPu-HQ7gtj` in my case.
4. Execute `lsblk -p -o +UUID` and look for the UUID of the Device Path that contains your `grub.cfg` file, `/dev/mapper/lvmpool-nix--root` with UUID `cc6a06bb-336f-4e9f-a5f0-fdd43e7f548f` in my case.

This will allow you to create the following extra GRUB menuentry for referencing our NixOS `grub.cfg` `configfile`, which is on my `nix-root` `lv` and because of the `boot.loader.grub.device = "nodev";` in my `/etc/nixos/configuration.nix` there is no GRUB installed for my NixOS installation (in Arch, this would go into `/etc/grub.d/40_custom`):

```
menuentry 'NixOS' {
    insmod crypto
    insmod cryptodisk
    insmod luks
    insmod lvm
    cryptomount -u a0cb535a8468485fa220a5f49e85c9f4
    set root='lvmid/5atKN9-PQBi-T9wb-Iyz8-qP4y-HN2E-c5uLOT/C9zkjF-IHu0-qQkP-KgLf-8rAy-TVPu-HQ7gtj'
    search --fs-uuid --set=root cc6a06bb-336f-4e9f-a5f0-fdd43e7f548f
    configfile '/boot/grub/grub.cfg'
}
```

To clarify this even more, this contains some literal values such as `lvmid` which is **not** supposed to be replaced with the name or ID of your LVM. This is not properly documented anywhere, it seems. The same issue applies for when your put the UUID of your LUKS device in the `cryptomount -u` line **with dashes** in it, GRUB will just tell you `Press any key to continue`, which is (obviously) not very helpful.

The bare template for a manual GRUB menuentry to boot from `crypt -> LVM -> root` with an [LVM on LUKS](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dm-crypt/Encrypting_an_entire_system#LVM_on_LUKS) setup would thus be:

```
menuentry 'NixOS' {
    insmod crypto
    insmod cryptodisk
    insmod luks
    insmod lvm
    cryptomount -u <LUKS UUID without dashes>
    set root='lvmid/<LVM Volume Group UUID>/<LVM Logical Volume UUID>'
    search --fs-uuid --set=root <Filesystem UUID>
    configfile '/boot/grub/grub.cfg'
}
```

For those who are interested in the other half also, I modified my `/etc/nixos/configuration.nix` file to look like this:

```
boot.loader.grub.enable = true;
boot.loader.grub.version = 2;
boot.loader.grub.device = "nodev";
boot.initrd.luks.devices = [ { name = "cryptroot"; device = "/dev/sda2"; preLVM = true; } ];
```